# How to trim, crop and add overlay in a single command using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using FFmpeg for video editing in android. I am able to trim, crop and add overlay using below commands:

For trim:

```
command = new String[]{"-i",inputVideoFilePath,"-ss","00:00:30.0","-c","copy","-t","00:00:10.0",outputVideoFilePath};
```

For crop:

```
command = new String[]{"-i",inputVideoFilePath,"-preset", "ultrafast","-filter:v","crop=400:400:0:0","-c:a","copy", outputVideoFilePath};
```

For overlay:

```
command = new String[]{"-i",inputVideoFilePath, "-i",overlayImagePath,"-preset", "ultrafast","-filter_complex", "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2", "-codec:a", "copy", outputVideoFilePath};
```

but I'm unable to merge these commands into a single command.
Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
command = new String[]{"-ss", "00:00:30.0", "-t", "00:00:10.0", "-i",inputVideoFilePath, 
          "-i",overlayImagePath, "-filter_complex",
          "[0]crop=400:400:0:0[a];[a][1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2",
          "-preset", "ultrafast", "-codec:a", "copy", outputVideoFilePath};
```

A filter_complex allows one to perform multiple filtering operations on different inputs in series or in parallel.

Comment: Thanx for help. I will try this.

Comment: working perfectly, btw is there any way to reduce processing time.